# Error Execution (22: 7): ORA-06550

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

HELLO I'm student and I'm new with oracle I trying somethings but have a problem with this procedure and I didnt find the where is it.I hope you can help me Thank you in advance..

error msg :
[Error] Execution (23: 7): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'URUNNOGEN'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

```
create or replace procedure ariciaykut.URUNNOGEN
(KATA in NVARCHAR2,MARK in NVARCHAR2,URNO out NVARCHAR2)as 
K NVARCHAR2(3);
M NVARCHAR2(3);
U NUMBER;
BEGIN
K:=KATA;
M:=MARK;
U:=0;
    FOR U IN 1..999 LOOP
        IF U BETWEEN '-1'AND'10' THEN
            URNO:=K||'00'||U||M;
        ELSIF U BETWEEN '9'AND'99' THEN
            URNO:=K||'0'||U||M;
        ELSE
            URNO:=K||U||M;
            INSERT INTO ARICIAYKUT.PROGOSTER VALUES(URNO);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

calling line:

```
EXEC ARICIAYKUT.URUNNOGEN('ICK','COC');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the out variable and declare as local variable

```
create or replace procedure ariciaykut.URUNNOGEN
(KATA in NVARCHAR2,MARK in NVARCHAR2)as 
K NVARCHAR2(3);
M NVARCHAR2(3);
U NUMBER;
Urno nvarchar2(100);
BEGIN
K:=KATA;
M:=MARK;
U:=0;
FOR U IN 1..999 LOOP
    IF U BETWEEN -1 AND 9 THEN
        URNO:=K||'00'||U||M;
    ELSIF U BETWEEN 9 AND 99 THEN
        URNO:=K||'0'||U||M;
    ELSE
        URNO:=K||U||M;
END IF;
        INSERT INTO ARICIAYKUT.PROGOSTER VALUES(URNO);

END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Edited the answer so the insert happens after checking the conditions

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one of your arguments to the procedure.  You define 3, but only specify 2 on the EXEC statement.

Comment: I think defining out is out of procedure isnt it? in the code I used it for this so how can call that? without anything, should I call it with ' ' like null? Because I want to be filled this area by procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing numeric values in `U` to strings (`'-1', '10'`, etc). This is very likely to end up doing something that you don't want. You're also counting on the default conversion of number to character to behave as you expect; you may be surprised.

Further, you've used the same name (`U`) for a variable and a loop control value, which will probably cause some confusion. (Inside the loop `U` will refer to the loop control value; outside the loop `U` will refer to the variable). I suggest you re-code your procedure to compare numbers to numbers, and to use the `TO_CHAR` function to convert numbers to character strings, similar to the following:

```
create or replace procedure ariciaykut.URUNNOGEN
    (KATA in NVARCHAR2,MARK in NVARCHAR2,URNO out NVARCHAR2)
as 
    K NVARCHAR2(3);
    M NVARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
    K:=KATA;
    M:=MARK;

    FOR U IN 1..999 LOOP
        URNO := K || TO_CHAR(U, '009') || M;

        IF U >= 100 THEN
            INSERT INTO ARICIAYKUT.PROGOSTER VALUES(URNO);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END URUNNOGEN;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem like this and thank you everyone who wanted to help me..

```
create or replace procedure ariciaykut.URUNNOGEN2 (KATA in NVARCHAR2,MARK in NVARCHAR2)as 
K NVARCHAR2(3);
M NVARCHAR2(3);
U NUMBER;
BEGIN
K:=KATA;
M:=MARK;
    FOR U IN 1..999 LOOP
        IF U BETWEEN '-1'AND'9' THEN
           INSERT INTO ARICIAYKUT.PROGOSTER VALUES(K||'00'||U||M);
        ELSIF U BETWEEN '9'AND'99' THEN
            INSERT INTO ARICIAYKUT.PROGOSTER VALUES(K||'0'||U||M);
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO ARICIAYKUT.PROGOSTER VALUES(K||U||M);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```